# Deploy Gatsby on Godaddy Sever

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Can I deploy Gatsby static pages on [Godaddy](https://in.godaddy.com/) server? I am not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SSH/SFTP access to your server on GoDaddy (which you should), you can use any CI tool to deploy your Gatsby site.

Tools you can use are for example:

- [Buddy](https://buddy.works/)
- [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/)

Another option is to use a hoster specialized on static pages like github pages or netlify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy your static website on a normal server without CI, you can run
`gatsby serve -p 80 -H <your private IP address>`. Replace  with the IP address you get from `ifconfig` on linux or `ipconfig` on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I end up building my own framework with `ReactJS`, now all I have to do is execute

> npm run build

to create an optimized build in build directory

1. Zip everything from build folder.
2. Go to godaddy CPanel->filemanger-> public html

[image]

[image]

3. Upload the zip file from build folder into public html
4. Right click to unzip it and we are good to go

See the live demo http://hiteshsahu.com/topics